# Make regular expression field optional which is displayed as mandatory field in MVC 4

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 4. I'm using Data Annotations  in model for validation.

There is one field name Mobile and validating using regular expression like below.

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{10}", ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number is Not Valid")]
public string Mobile { get; set; }
```

As per the application requirement above field is not mandatory but need to validate Mobile number if user insert it.

My problem is that when I submit form it displays "Mobile field is required." but the mobile field is not decorate with `[Required]` attribute. So How it display as required?

What could be the reason?
How to solve it?

Comment: does mobile field in the database is allowed to have null?, In case if u r trying to store the value into the database and field is not allowed to have null, system throws same error.

Comment: Yes Mobile field in the database is allowed null.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it very easily using following simple jQuery..

```
//Remove Required field validation on pin and mobile number
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Mobile").removeAttr("data-val");
    });
```

Pls try and let me us know if that works for you or not.

Thanks

Comment: This method does not seem to do anything for me. Empty fields still fire the regular expression validation. It would seem that regular expression validation carries a `required` validation along with it. Is there no way to prevent this problem that doesn't seem like a hack?

Answer (score 0):

In your project, there is a folder "views" where you probably created your view with your needed controls.
there should be something like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mobile)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mobile)<br />
```

in order to make the regularExpression work.
If you already did this, another problem could be your model.
At the top of your view you should add your model by:

```
@model yourModelName
```

Comment: He is asking to make that field only validate Input, but still leaving it as optional.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not post any code in you controller, `Index` is assumed as action of your controller and `MyModel` is assumed as model.

Try the following code in your controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
       //This will check if `Mobile` is empty and remove the Mobile from validation if the field is empty
       if (collection.Get("Mobile") == "")  //Mobile is the name of the Mobile number field in view
       {
            ModelState.Remove("Mobile");
       }
       if(ModelState.IsValid){
       //do something
       }
       else{
             return View(model);
       }
    }
```

Hope it helps